# Grep errors from a file and put them in a new file but not override new file

Tags: linux, bash

Tried to run a bash script for this as I want to put this into cron and run every night to pull out errors from a file and write to a file in same directory:

My script which just hangs and pulls out nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i "error" > /var/log/syserrorlog.log
```

When this runs I would like this to write to/update the same file and not override it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `>` to `>>` (the latter means append). Also, `tail -f` will hang by definition: it monitors files for new data.

If your syslog is rotated every day, then you can simply use

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "error" >> /var/log/syserrorlog.log
```

If it is not rotated, you can add a `grep` to the pipeline which filters out the relevant date

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try this tomorrow morning and let you know the outcome 

Comment: Perfect... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `logrotate`. This is daemon used to periodically rotate logs (e.g. archive logs files and then clear them every night). It supports many configuration options, one of them is `postrotate` - custom script executed after rotation is done. Description copied from `logrotate`'s man page:

> **postrotate/endscript**
>
> The lines between postrotate and endscript (both of which must appear on lines by themselves) are executed (using /bin/sh) after the
>   log file is rotated. These directives may only appear inside a log
>   file definition. Normally, the absolute path to the log file is passed
>   as first argument to the script. If sharedscripts is specified, whole
>   pattern is passed to the script. See also prerotate. See sharedscripts
>   and nosharedscripts for error handling.

Syslog is a standard daemon too, so it should have configuration file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`. You could add your commands there.